# Should I use Dialog or DialogPreference to make a specialized preference dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, sharedpreferences, dialog-preference

I'm trying to make a custom setting in my application's `PreferenceActivity` that brings up a `Dialog` which will ultimately have the following

1. An `EditText` to specify a server
2. A `Button` for testing the server connection
3. A response `Icon` specifying if the server has been reached

I am making some progress creating a custom `Dialog`, but I've also encountered the `DialogPreference` class which seems to be useful for this type of feature.

I'm wondering if there is any reason for me to start trying to use `DialogPreference` or if it is reasonable for me to continue toying around with a simple custom `Dialog`.

Will I run into any problems with either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the `DialogPreference`. `DialogPreference` is provided to you for this exact situation. And you should not run into any problems.

However, if you are already almost done... then continue with what you have.

Also, if you are wanting your `DialogPreference` to launch other dialogs, like confirmations or whatever, you should use `Dialog`.

Comment: What would be the best way to use DialogPreference. The implementation seems rather messy and I'm finding very little documentation. Maybe you have a good resource you could direct me to?

Comment: The only thing that i do to get it to work correctly is just override `onCreateDialogView()`. Set the `Dialog` layout with `setDialogLayoutResource(...)` and get the `View` with `super.onCreateView()`. I have done this a couple times with stuff where i work and it works fine.